# Rounding UP double values in java based on parameters

Tags: java

I have the following scenario , let us assume 125,250,500 are rounding parameter based on which we have to do rounding.

1. when the rounding parameter is 125 then I need to round off to 1/8 th dollar,
   ie, value = 10.01 then it should return 10.125
   value = 110.2 then it should return 110.250
2. when the rounding parameter is 250 then I need to round off to quarter dollar,
   ie, value = 10.01 then it should return 10.250
   value = 110.3 then it should return 110.500
3. when the rounding parameter is 500 then I need to round off to half dollar,
   ie, value = 10.01 then it should return 10.500
   value = 110.6 then it should return 111.

I have written code using Math.round(8f * value/8f) which rounds of to nearest 1/8 th dollar but the rounding should be UP always but in my case 10.01 rounds off to 10

Answer (score 3):

First off, you're not rounding, you're doing a ceiling.

This code does what you want:

```
Math.ceil(n * 1000 / factor) * factor / 1000;
```

Here is the code bundled as a method:

```
public static double ceil(double n, int factor) {
    return Math.ceil(n * 1000 / factor) * factor / 1000;
}
```

Note that no casting is required, because in java arithemtic if one of the operands is `double`, the others are automatically (and safely) widened to `double` too.

Answer (score 1):

> I have written code using Math.round(8f * value/8f) which rounds of to nearest 1/8 th dollar

No it doesn't. It rounds to the nearest integer.

Try for example `Math.round(((8f+1/8f) * value))/8f.`

Answer (score 1):

Break it down to manageable steps, no value trying to do it on one line. So:

How many 1/8th dollars are there in value?

```
float dollar8ths = value * 8f;
```

Round that up:

```
int dollar8thsRoundedUp = (int) Math.ceil(dollar8ths);
```

Finally, put back into dollars:

```
float dollars = dollar8thsRoundedUp / 8f;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
double myRound(double val, int param)
{
    val = 1000 * val / param;
    val = Math.ceil(val);
    return val * param / 1000;
}
```

e.g.:

```
System.out.println(myRound(10.01, 125));
```

gives

```
10.125
```